# Replacement for SQL query with stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2016

```
public DataTable GetRandomQuestionByCateId(string id, int z)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM tblQuestions where CategoryId=@a ORDER BY QId OFFSET @z ROWS  FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY";

    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[] 
            { 
                new SqlParameter("@a",id),
                new SqlParameter("@z",z),
            };

    return DAO.GetTable(sql, param);
}
```

I have this code segment and want to execute a stored procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRandomQuest
    (@a int,
     @b int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM tblQuestions 
    WHERE CategoryId = @a
    ORDER BY QId
        OFFSET @b ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
END

EXEC dbo.GetRandomQuest `@a=2`, `@b=1`
```

How can I replace it in above case?

Comment: what you want to replace? your question is not clear enough and are confusing  as well

Comment: `I`  want to execute storedprocedure instead of sqlquery.

Comment: @ParasMaharjan So you want to know what changes to be made in the code?

Comment: yes if that helps

Comment: It is really easy to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the execusion is happening inside the `DAO.GetTable()` method but it is not provided in the question, no problem, you can modify the signature of the `GetRandomQuestionByCateId` to execute stored procedure instead of sqlquery. the changes will be like the following:

```
public DataTable GetRandomQuestionByCateId(string id, int z)
{
    DataTable resultData;
    String sqlProcedure = "GetRandomQuest";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string here")) 
    {
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) 
       {
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = a;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@z", SqlDbType.int).Value = z;   
          SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          da.Fill(resultData);          
       }
    }
    return resultData;
}
```

Key points to note, by using `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` you are specifying that you wanted to execute a stored procedure, in this case the commandText will be the name of the procedure and you can add parameters to the command as like what you are doing currently.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public DataTable GetRandomQuestionByCateId(string id, int z)
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetRandomQuest", conn) ;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = z;
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public DataTable GetRandomQuestion(int id, int z)
    {
        ArrayList sqlParameterArrayList = new ArrayList();

        SqlParameter sqpID = new SqlParameter("a", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqpID.Value = id;
        sqlParameterArrayList.Add(sqpID);

        SqlParameter sqpZ = new SqlParameter("b", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqpZ.Value = z;
        sqlParameterArrayList.Add(sqpZ);

        return DAO.GetTable("GetRandomQuest", sqlParameterArrayList);
    }
```

I changed the datatype for id to int because that's what you're expecting in your stored procedure. Just do those changes as required. Hope this helps.